# Is it possible to use .data() as a search criteria?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a pretty complex chat application going on, and there are multiple chat panes, chat entries, chat submits, etc. going on in the same window. At first I was going to do something like....

```
<input type="text" class="chattext" id="chattext-42">
<input type="text" class="chattext" id="chattext-93">
<input type="button" class="chatsubmit" id="chatsubmit-42">
<input type="button" class="chatsubmit" id="chatsubmit-93">
```

... etc. (of course this is vastly simplified, they'd be in separate divs, separate visibilities, etc) So, when they clicked on a .chatsubmit, it would then get the id of that and find the last two characters for the chat ID. This presents some problems, as it would require rewrites if IDs changed lengths, and seems just plain inelegant to me.

I then remembered the .data() facility in jQuery... I thought, maybe I could do it more like this:

```
<input type="text" class="chattext"> ... and add a .data("id", 42) to this one
<input type="button" class="chatsubmit"> ... and add a .data("id", 42)
```

So that when they click chatsubmit, it gets the ID, and then finds the chattext with that ID and processes it. But looking at the documentation, I don't see an easy way to search by this. For example, let's say the event target in this case is the chatsubmit with the data('id') of 42...

```
var ID = $(event.target).data('id'); // Sets it to 42
var chattext = ...
```

And here I run into the trouble. How do I find which DOM element matches a class of chattext and a data('id') of 42? Is there any easy method, or do I have to search every .chattext for the one with an id of 42? Or is there another easy way of doing this?

I did consider the possibility of the container div having the ID, which would make it, I think,? slightly easier to get. But if this works, it could be dealing with things in other container divs as well, making that not a long-term solution.

Edit: Literally seconds after posting this, I found this: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/ which includes information on extending the selector to data. So I'll try that out, and in the meantime, is this a completely foolhardy way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with using "id", and it's definitely going to be the fastest way to find things.  If you're careful with the pattern you use (say, always placing the numeric key after a "-" or "_" character) then you can just use a regex to split the key value:

```
  var key = $(this).attr('className').replace(/-(\d+)$/, "$1");
```

or whatever.

Of course, you can still use the "data" feature to also store the key, if fetching it from the "id" value seems ugly.  It wouldn't bother me, however.

*edit* — if you wanted to "clean it up" even more, you could always write a couple of jQuery plugins to make it possible to get the key, and to return a selector to be used to find "partner" elements of a given one.

Comment: For some reason, regexes rarely occur to me. So I think you've convinced me. Thanks!